# FactoryGirl - create_list increments parameter for each object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm trying to use RSpec's create_list in a way that, for a specific column, each object receives the value of the previous object + 1.

If Rails accepted ++ notation, it would be something like this:

```
create_list :entity, 10, priority: priority++
```

I tried using sequence, but the problem is the sequence never resets. I need priority to always start from 1.

How could I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the surroundings of this line?

Comment: `trait :with_10_recipients do
      after(:create) do |flow|
        create_list :flow_recipient, 10, flow: flow
      end
    end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think this is possible with `create_list`. Due to the way method calling works in Ruby, the arguments you pass to `create_list` are evaluated immediately and are not re-evaluated for each new `Entity` that is being created.

How about this instead?

```
(1..10).map do |priority|
  create :entity, priority: priority
end
```